# Importing old tables from removed postgresql to the newly inistalled postgresql

Tags: postgresql, import

I had a problem with my postgresql and I copy all the files and then removed it.
Then , i install the fresh one and the problem is solved.
Now is is possible to import the old files and tebles to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are the same major version (i.e. 9.0 to 9.0.4, not 9.0 to 9.1) then you can just start up in the old data directory and get everything.  PostgreSQL does not have a simple import facility for table files, and so if you want to pull only some tables in, your best bet is `pg_dump -c` followed by `pg_restore -t tablename` so you can selectively restore tables to your new cluster.